# How to use Group by from a Dataview values in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ado.net, dataset

is there any way to use group by on datatview values.i can sort the values in dataview but how  to group the data in data view (in vb.net)
 i want to apply the aggregate function on a dataview  how make it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can group objects from a `DataView` or any other data collection using the [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method extension.

For a DataView you'd first have to cast it as `IEnumerable(Of DataRowView)`. Here's a very simplistic example:

```
Dim groupedRows =
    myDataView.Cast(Of DataRowView).GroupBy(Function(r) r("MyField"))
```

If you're using a typed `DataSet` you might find it much easier to group on typed `DataRow` instead as you'll be able to use hard properties for grouping rather than `Object` values obtained with string references:

```
Dim groupedRows =
    myDataTable.GroupBy(function(r) r.MyField)
```

Comment: thanks  but i dont know how to do this can you show an example

Comment: @jyothis I just edited my answer, have a look. Also check out the link I provided, it will give you all the information you may need on how to use the method.